# Declaring Jquery object as variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery and javascript.

While I was writing a javascript code, I found myself using a particular jquery object often, so I declared a variable for it. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var object_list = $("#object_list");

    /*Do something with the variable*/        
    alert(object_list);
    object_list.hide();
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work ("alert(object_list)" gives me a null value).

Is declaring a variable like this wrong in jquery???

If so, then what is the right way so that I can refer to commonly used Jquery object??\

Thanks!

Comment: it is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YVYWP/1/

Comment: A `null` value? Did you somehow overwrite `$`, for example by loading Prototype.js?

Comment: @Bergi I join my voice to you, the alert should show an Object even if the selector doesn't much anything, so yes, good point, `$()` here is not an alias to `jQuery()`.

Comment: @NabilKadimi as a matter of fact, it should return an `Array`, empty or containing one or more HtmlElement objects.

Comment: @KooiInc - I would say it's an empty jQuery object - http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/YVYWP/4/

Comment: Use Firebug to see if you are getting any errors / warnings.  It provides you with a wealth of tools, so that you don't have to use alert to try and guess what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery is  probably working in [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), which means that you detached the alias `$ = jQuery` somewhere earlier in your code. WordPress for example does that (see latest line of [wp-includes/js/jquery.js](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js#L5)).

Use this code instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var object_list = $("#object_list");

    /*Do something with the variable*/        
    alert(object_list);
    object_list.hide();
});
```

What you are doing is aliasing the jQuery object within the `.ready` method, see the section for **Aliasing the jQuery Namespace** in the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your code inside an immediate function to avoid naming collision with `$`. This technique is useful when you already have a lot of code using the `$` and refactoring to change the name may be error-prone.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var object_list = $("#object_list");

     /*Do something with the variable*/        
      alert(object_list);
      object_list.hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```